# What method to use to make a Servlet thread-safe?

Tags: java, servlets, thread-safety

I am trying to make a servlet thread-safe with sessions. I have read up on different techniques such as a synchronized block, AtomicReference or ConcurrentHashMap. What are the trade-offs for each technique, if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first aim for a servlet is to achieve thread safety by virtue of no shared state. Any shared state will fail to be that when the servlet is deployed into a load-balancing cluster. So if your shared state is not of a *cache* flavor, meaning it can always be rebuilt from a durable store, you shouldn't have it in the first place.

But, apart from these concerns, you cannot get a one-size-fits-all answer without giving any details on the problem you are trying to solve with shared state. All the techniques you mention have merit, that's why they are still around with us after 15 years of experience with Java.

Answer (score 1):

A servlet should not have state, i.e. instance or static variables that are affected by its request processing methods anyway (additionally its request processing methods should not affect the state of any shared objects). There is only one servlet instance per servlet container and each request is processed using a new Thread that runs the appropriate Servlet method (more commonly doGet() or doPost()).

However, the servlet API provides all the functionality required to store data with respect to a specific user session in a thread-safe manner out of the box. For instance, you could get the session by HttpServletRequest#getSession() and use its setAttribute() method to store objects in the specific session and getAttribute() to get them back on another request of the same session.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, servlets should be stateless, which is good for the scalability of application. Actucally, Session Object based on Servlet API is highly extendable, you can write your own   HttpSession implementation to make the Session access thread-safe. 
IMHO, you should provide some more details of your scenario, because in those data structures you mentioned above, the last two seems have nothing to do with the thread-safe access of Session.